# How to get an integer value from SQL database to a variable in windows forms (C#)?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I've created a form called `BookSeat` which takes ***no.of seats*** as an input and calculate the total fare.

Here's my code:

```
        {
            try
            {
                DB db = new DB();

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT [fare] FROM [dbo].[Train] WHERE name = '" + textBoxName.Text + "' ";
                cmd.Connection = db.GetConnection();

                db.openConnection();

                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                dr.Read();

                int d = dr.GetInt32(0);

                int noOfSeats = comboBoxNoOfSeats.SelectedIndex;

                int totalfare;

                totalfare = noOfSeats * d;

                textBoxTotalFare.Text = totalfare.ToString();

                db.closeConnection();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            
        }
```

This shows and error : **Invalid attempt to read when no data is present**

Comment: DO you have data in your DB table?

Comment: There's no excuse for not using parameterized queries.

Comment: @Sh.Imran yes. The column fare is the 9th column and it has data inside it

Comment: Execute the query on your database using Management Studio. Are you sure you're querying for an existing record? Are you even connecting to the database you think you are?

Comment: Obligatory https://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score -1):

`SqlDataReader` has the method called `Read` which reads all the data inside `sqldatareader`. But you have to call this function inside `while` loop.

```
try
{
    DB db = new DB();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT [fare] FROM [dbo].[Train] WHERE name = '" + textBoxName.Text + "' ";
    cmd.Connection = db.GetConnection();
    db.openConnection();

    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    While(dr.Read())
    {
        //Get value by using column name;
        int d = Convert.ToInt32(dr["columnname"]);
        int noOfSeats = comboBoxNoOfSeats.SelectedIndex;
        int totalfare;
        totalfare = noOfSeats * d;
        textBoxTotalFare.Text = totalfare.ToString();
    }

    dr.Close();
    db.closeConnection();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: _"you have to call this function inside while loop"_ - not if you're expecting one record. This code will yield the same error and does not fix the problem, nor does it address the SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: Yeah right, but how can we get the single record when the above scenario take place.

Comment: Then you just call `dr.Read()` once, just as the OP is doing.

Comment: @CodeCaster But I think my answer is on right track. I always use Reader.Read inside while and retrive the information from SqlDataReader